# upgrading ejabberd from 16.09-4 to latest

Tags: mysql, debian, updates, ejabberd, mnesia

Back in september '17 I installed an ejabberd-instance on a  (debian 9-)server my dad still pays for, but is no longer using. The small circle of friends that initially used it, quickly grew and now there's a few hundred of us chatting away.

Time has come to update the ejabberd (I installed 16.09-4) because we want to stay secure and be able to enjoy all the latest whistles and bells. I thought some simple 'apt-get upgrade'-magic would do the trick, but boy, was I wrong.

I looked at the docs ([Specific version upgrade notes](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/upgrade/)) and tried to update to 17.03, by following the steps described there.
These updates fail miserably (missing links to /usr/sbin/ causing failure to to restart server after update. Adding symlinks does not help. I believe I chose to install to /opt/ last year, which would explain why).

Since I have some experience with MySQL and none whatsoever with Mnesia, I also decided in the beginning to add "default_db : SQL" in my ejabberd.yml file. I (wrongly) assumed all data would be stored in a MySQL-DB, and no longer in the Mnesia. This does not seem to be the case: I see all of the registered users in Mnesia (using ejabberdctl) but only part of the complete list in MySQL.

I guess my question is twofold:

- What would be the most efficient way to update from 16.09-4 to the latest version ? (I am aiming for a solution without having to install a new ejabberd-instance on a different server and simply backing up and migrating the MySQL)
- How can I avoid using Mnesia completely and only use MySQL ? And, related: How can I push all existing Mnesia-data into MySQL ?

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the most efficient way to update from 16.09-4 to the latest version ?

As you have some kind of confusion about what and where is installed, problems in links, paths, etc, I propose as "the most efficient" a solution that has many many steps, but at least will work whatever you have:

First handle the old one:

1. Find your config dir and mnesia spool (try 'ejabberdctl help')
2. Stop ejabberd
3. Move to a safe location your config dir and mnesia spool
4. Uninstall ejabberd and all ejabberd related files and dirs

Now comes the new one:

5. Install ejabberd in the way you prefer: Debian package, source, whatever
6. Let it start, so it creates default config files and minimal mnesia spool
7. You can even register an account, login, check it runs correctly
8. Find the new config dir and mnesia spool (maybe they are different paths due to different install process)
9. Stop ejabberd

And now recover your old information

10. Replace the new config dir with old one, and the new mnesia spool with your old one
11. Start ejabberd again, with old config and old mnesia. It may complain about useless or unknown options, it may also report it's updating the database schema.
12. If it at least starts, check you have all the users, and also update the config file in case there were renamed options...

Of course, there are easier and faster ways to update, but your special case requires special steps.

> How can I avoid using Mnesia completely and only use MySQL ?

Why exactly do you want to avoid it at all costs? It's required for some stuff in ejabberd, like client sessions, internal routes, commands... Other stuff can be moved to MySQL, like roster, passwd, MUC, vcards...

> And, related: How can I push all existing Mnesia-data into MySQL ?

You can configure many modules to use sql instead of mnesia, and then run the export2sql command that produces a *.sql file that you will import into your new MySQL database. After that, you can delete content of mnesia tables using the WebAdmin.

Comment: Very clear and simple to follow. Muchos gracias Badlop !